# Check if xml files contain specific tags in PHP

Tags: php, xml

I got a xml files something like:

```
<model_info>
    <status>available</status>
    <model_name>Alexia</model_name>
</model_info>
```

now in my php codes, i want to check if the xml files contain `<status></status>` tags.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($xml_path);
//if xml contain <status></status> tags-->
  {
   $model_name = $xml->model_name;
  } else { exit; }
```

Can someone advise what is the right way or syntax to check this condition?

Comment: I edited my answer to include the status tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use Xpath: `$result = $xml->xpath('//model_name[../status]');`

And use `count($result)` to count how many hits are present in `$result`.

Comment: okay, but i need to check the status tags, why there's //model_name? do you mean //model_info?

Comment: @Ren In your own question you want to have model_name. So that's why `//model_name`.  And because you want to have a sibling called status, you do `[../status]`, whichc actually means 'look inside the parent for a status tag'.

Comment: Owh, no, i mean check if the <status></status> tags exist then save the model_name, if not exist then exit code.

Comment: i think i just use $result = $xml->xpath('status'); and i found everything goes like what i want. ^^

Answer (score 2):

(Just showing a solution with SimpleXML since it's what you used in your question)

The best way I found to deal with this it to use `getName()` on a node, and check if it is empty (`== ''`).

Otherwise, you could have issues with nodes like `<something></something>` with some other types of checks based on node value.

```
$str = '<model_info>
    <status>available</status>
    <model_name>Alexia</model_name>
</model_info>';

$xml = simplexml_load_string($str);


function node_exists($simplexml_node) {
  return $simplexml_node->getName() != '';
}

var_dump(node_exists($xml->model_name));
var_dump(node_exists($xml->model_oh_nooooo));
```

Output :

```
bool(true)
bool(false)
```

So with your example :

```
$str = '<model_info>
    <model_name>Alexia</model_name>
</model_info>';

$xml = simplexml_load_string($str);


function node_exists($simplexml_node) {
  return $simplexml_node->getName() != '';
}

if (node_exists($xml->status)) {
  $model_name = $xml->model_name;
}

var_dump($model_name);
```

Output :

```
NULL
```

Comment: I've tried this code, but when i delete the status tags, the condition is still true.

Comment: @Ren Uh, it works well for me. If I remove `<status>`, $model_name = NULL. I don't know how you tried it. Which node did you check/sent ? I updated my answer to give the whole code and the output

Comment: I tried it like this if (node_exists($xml->status)) { echo "true"; } else { echo "false";} . No matter the tags exist or not, it always true.

Comment: @Ren I can't help you much more then. I used the exact XML structure you gave and I provided all the code needed to reproduce the solution.

Comment: i run exactly like your codes and i get this result "object(SimpleXMLElement)#2 (1) { [0]=> string(6) "Alexia" }" . It goes the same if the status tags exist or not. any idea?